# When to use %, px, em, etc...?

Tags: css

I am pretty new to CSS, and would like to know if there is/are some sort of rule/rules of thumb for determining when to use different units to define layouts. Currently I have everything defined in %, because I thought that'd be good for window resizing. That is not the case, text starts to overflow, images get screwed around and so on. 
Any help will be appreceiated.

Comment: I'm not an expert, so I can't really give you advice on when to use which unit, but here's an article that I came across just today. It's a bit old, but explains some of the basics pretty well: http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=199

Comment: My vote is to use physical units of measure: `1in`, `1mm`, `1cm` so that your text is theoretically the same size regardless of screen size/resolution.  Short of that, use `ex` as it is just better than `em`.  :D

Comment: @Nathan D. Ryan, very useful resource, thanks.

Comment: @cwolves - That bothers me, because `ex` is a measurement of *height* while `em` is a measurement of *width*

Comment: @Stephen P - Yeah, I wasn't serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using percentages to have a layout work in different size viewports is a very advanced technique, and is often done dynamically using javascript. Until you are more familiar with CSS, and can look at working percentage based layouts and understand enough to replicate it, you are better sticking to PX.

If you are going the javascript route it is really quite simple. For a start use jQuery as it makes resizing your layout a breeze compared to trying to do it with native javascript. Then $(window).height(); gives you the height of the viewport; $(window).width(); gives you the width. You set a default px width for your container, and then use percentages for all other block level elements (containers, within the container, sidebar, main etc) and do this:

```
function percentagize() {
var height = $(window).height()-100;
var width = $(window).width()-20;
$("div#container").css({
'height' : height+'px',
'width' : width+'px',
'margin': '0 auto'
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
percentagize();
$(window).bind('resize','percentagize');
})
```

Comment: I am quite familiar with javascript. Perhaps you know of some resources I can look at to achieve this? I am building a website for fashion designers, so I am placing a huge priority on aesthetics. I am not concerned about the learning time.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, I use the following

- Layouts - Pixel (Unless something needs to be a % width/height)
- Fonts - Pixel (Sometimes % for accessibility, but it is a nightmare to maintain)

Generally speaking, you can use pixels most of the time. The font issue is a more complex one. For instance, if you want the "increase font-size" features to work within a browser without resizing the rest of the page, you need to use %'s. However, when using % font sizes, a child element always inherits the parents font-size, so you get the following:

```
body { font-size:87%; }
h1 { font-size:87%; }
```

This will mean that the `h1` is actually 87% of 87%. This can be quite annoying. As you end up with percentages > 100%. It gets very thick fast, and is best avoided.

I'm not sure if em's work in the same way, I've never looked into them in great detail.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea: http://w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

% is not explained properly on that page, but it means x% of the containing block.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ems for fonts so that they are always relatively sized... by default they are 1 em or 16px... you can set play with this by setting `body { font-size: 75% }` which makes 1em the equivalent of 12px [The PxtoEm calculator is great](http://pxtoem.com/). From here you can do things like

```
h1 { font-size: 3em }
p { font-size: 1em }
```

now no matter what you set that body font size to the h1 tag will always be 3 times larger than a paragraph. It gives more flexibility and keeps yout type hierachy proportional.

For layouts it really depends on the layout type... for the classic fixed with central column then use pixels.... for fluid or adaptive layouts then use percentages (or a mix of fixed width, i.e. left hand nav bar andpercentages)

Answer (score 0):

Use **em** as much as possible, since this is the most maintainable. The em unit depends on the font size of the current element, so if you change the base font size, em-units scale along.

Use **px** in screen style sheets when you need a fixed size. Typically you would specify the size of the base font in pixels. Image sizes should also be specified in px, since an image should not scale up or down just because you change a font - it will just make the image blurry. Also border thicknesses should probably be specified in pixels, since you don't want it to depend on font sizes.

Use **pt**, **pc**, **in**, **cm**, **mm** only in print media style sheets. You probably wouldn't to mix metric and imperial in the same style sheet, so decide on either in or cm/mm.

**%** is tricky since it means something different depending on the property. For font-sizes, 100% = 1em, so its just a matter of preference if you like % or em. (I prefer em for font sizes, since % have different meaning in other contexts.) It is not affected by window scaling though. The font size doesn't scale with the window size, and neither does em or % units.

For width and height on boxes, % refers to percent of the size of the parent box, which for the root element is depending on the window size. This is much less useful than it sounds! For example if you have a flow of text without any specified width, the lines will become too long to read comfortably. If you specify the width of the text box in em's you can give it a nice readable line-length, on any screen. But if you specify the width in % it will scale with the size of the window, which means it can still be too long on some screens and to short on others. Scaling with the window size sounds good in theory, but is rarely what you want.